# wx python windows can't hide my MenuBar

Tags: python, wxpython

Yop, all is in title, i wanna Hide my wx.MenuBar() on my soft, and that is works well on my Ubuntu, but when i switch my soft on Windows, my wx.MenuBar() is not hide... Any Ideas?

```
    menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
    self.fileMenu = wx.Menu()
    i = self.fileMenu.Append(-1, _("Load Model\tCTRL+L"))
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.showLoadModel(), i)
    menuBar.Append(self.fileMenu, 'File')
    self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)
    menuBar.Hide()
```

EDIT: Then how can i catch a CTRL+L without EVT_MENU ?

Comment: I think it cannot be hidden in Windows. Not sure tough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok i found it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kw) 

        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):

        pnl = wx.Panel(self)
        pnl.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKeyDown)
        pnl.SetFocus()

        self.SetSize((250, 180))
        self.SetTitle('Key event')
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)  

    def OnKeyDown(self, e):

        key = e.GetKeyCode()

        if key == wx.WXK_ESCAPE:

            ret  = wx.MessageBox('Are you sure to quit?', 'Question', 
                wx.YES_NO | wx.NO_DEFAULT, self)

            if ret == wx.YES:
                self.Close()               

def main():

    ex = wx.App()
    Example(None)
    ex.MainLoop()
```